# How to sort dictionary in alphabetical order?

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise where given a CSV file `message.csv` (the first three lines of which are displayed below), I need to write a program to count the number of messages from each sender, then print the output in alphabetical order by sender.

*Sender,Message 

"hello there!" 

"Computing is damn hard!"*

This is what I have tried so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
counting = defaultdict(int)
for row in csv.reader(open(message.csv)):
    counting[row[0]] += 1
```

I'm stuck on how to continue.

Comment: After that try something like: for each in sorted(counting.keys()): print each, counting[each] ...

Comment: Jim Dennis thank you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it assumes that the first value of each line is the sender but the 3 lines of the .csv file you've given us don't comply with this.

Based on the actual first 3 lines of the csv file, I would do:

```
sender = None
for row in csv.reader(open(message.csv)):
    if len(row) == 2:
        sender = row[0]
    counting[sender] += 1
```

and then as Jim Dennis says, but you shouldn't call .keys() explicitly:

```
for sender in sorted(counting):
    print sender, counting[sender]
```